# How can I access views of an activity from a non activity class?

Tags: android

I am trying of access a view from a non activity class, but I am not sure how to do it

After looking at some other sources, I understand I must pass the Context like this

```
public Manager(Context c) {
        context = c;

    }
```

but when I try c.findViewById() it doesnt work. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public Manager(Activity a) {
        Activity = a;
    }
```

then do

```
a.findViewById
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your view a public static variable, you can access it from anywhere in your application.

for example:
In your Activity class, use

```
public static TextView mTextView = null;
```

In its `onCreate()`, initialize the `TextView`.

Now from any other class, you can always use:

```
myActivity.mTextView
```

to access the `TextView`

Comment: Never create static views it may leads to memory leaks